# Can I export a drawing made in blender to a 2d file?

Tags: export

I created a model and drew an outline on the surface. Is there anyway to choose an angle and save only the lines to create a PSD file or a 2d vector (just the lines, no BG)? I wanted to use it as line art that I can color in.

Comment: just render the file with a transparent background.

Comment: @susu How so I save it with just the lines? The object shows even when I disable the view.